# Find 2x2 constant matrix which has given solution x for linear ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x' = Ax$, where $x(t) = [e^{-t}(cos(t) + 2sin(t); e^{-t}cos(t)].$

I've tried to go about solving this by going "backwards" with regards to how one normally solves these types of problems and I have found the eigenvalues by inspection. I also get an equation system whose purpose is to find the exact values of the elements of the eigenvector $v$. Problem is I don't this system has solutions. My thought is that if I have $\lambda$ and $v$ then I can solve for A in equation $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. I might also need some equation gathered from the characteristic equation but that's a problem later down the line.

So I am stuck at my failed equation system and don't know what to make of this. If anyone can solve it or put me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using complex exponentials, write this as 
$$x = e^{(-1+i)t} \pmatrix{1/2 - i\cr 1/2\cr} + e^{(-1-i)t} \pmatrix{1/2 + i\cr 1/2\cr} $$
You want $A$ to have eigenvalue $-1+i$ with eigenvector $ \pmatrix{1/2 - i\cr 1/2\cr}$ and eigenvalue $-1-i$ with eigenvector $\pmatrix{1/2 + i\cr 1/2\cr}$.  A suitable $A$ is $U D U^{-1}$ where $U$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! It took quite some time to get my expression to the complex exponential form. I wrote $x(t) = c_1*\Re{(e^{\lambda_1t}v_1)}+c_2*\Im{(e^{\lambda_1t}v_1})}$ and proceeded from there. Is there a faster way?

Comment: $\cos(x) = (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2$, $\sin(x) = i(e^{-ix} - e^{ix})/2$.